# Term query on nested fields returns no result in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a nested type field in my mapping. When I use **Term** search query on my nested field no result is returned from Elasticsearch whereas when I change **Term** to **Match** query, it works fine and Elasticsearch returns expected result

here is my mapping, imagine I have only one nested field in my type mapping

```
{
"homing.estatefiles": {
    "mappings": {
        "estatefile": {
            "properties": {
                "DynamicFields": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "Name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "ValueBool": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        },
                        "ValueDateTime": {
                            "type": "date"
                        },
                        "ValueInt": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is my term query (which returns no result)

```
{
 "from": 50,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
   "bool": {
   "filter": [
    {
      "nested": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "DynamicFields.Name":{"value":"HasParking"}
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "DynamicFields.ValueBool": {
                    "value": true
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "path": "DynamicFields"
      }
    }
  ]
  }
 }
}
```

And here is my query which returns expected result (by changing Term query to Match query)

```
{
 "from": 50,
 "size": 50,
 "query": {
  "bool": {
   "filter": [
    {
      "nested": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "DynamicFields.Name":"HasParking"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "DynamicFields.ValueBool": {
                    "value": true
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "path": "DynamicFields"
      }
     }
    ]
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the capital letters with the analyzer of elastic.

When you are using `term` the elastic is looking for the exact value you gave.
up until now it sounds good, **but** before it tries to match the term, the value you gave go through an analyzer of elastic which manipulate your value. 
For example in your case it also turn the `HasParking` to `hasparking`.

And than it will try to match it and of course will fail. They have a great explanation in the [documentation in the "Why doesn’t the term query match my document"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2//query-dsl-term-query.html) section. This analyzer not being activated on the value when you query using `match` and this why you get your result.